# How To Fill Table Cells Without Sticking to Another Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix

I want to call a function to generate row an column pair as string to fill a table cell with at least 1 cell gap between theme like this.
[image]

as you see in image there is 1 empty cell between filled cells.
a have an array like this to fill table cells:

```
arr=['1,1','4,2'] //which means fill row 4 column 2 td
```

i generate random number pair and if generated number pair is repetitive then i remove it and generate again while arr length reach a specific length
here is my function:

```
         /* each level has a fill cell count */
         while($brightCells.length < $brightCellsCount){        
            /* browser will break if it is infinite loop */
            if($generateCount > 5000){
                clearTimeout($playTimeInterval);
                playGame();
                return  false;
            }
            $r = getRandom(1,$rowCount);
            $c = getRandom(1,$columnCount);
            $brightCells.push($r+','+$c);
            $brightCells = $brightCells.filter(onlyUnique);
            /*یک سطر بعد*/
            if($.inArray( ($r+1) +',' + $c , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک سطر قبل*/
            if($.inArray( ($r-1) +',' + $c , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون بعد*/
            if($.inArray( $r +',' + ($c+1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون قبل*/
            if($.inArray( $r +',' + ($c-1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون قبل و یک سطر قبل*/
            if($.inArray( ($r-1) +',' + ($c-1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون بعد  و یک سطر قبل*/
            if($.inArray( ($r-1) +',' + ($c+1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون بعد  و یک سطر قبل*/
            if($.inArray( ($r+1) +',' + ($c-1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
            /*یک ستون بعد  و یک سطر بعد*/
            if($.inArray( ($r+1) +',' + ($c+1) , $brightCells ) !== -1){
                $brightCells.pop();
            }
        }
```

the code works fine but sometimes it goes to infinite loop.
is there any other algorithm to fill table with gap?

Comment: Don't push the new cell until *after* you've checked whether any of the adjacent cells are in the array.

Comment: @Barmar it will cause crash browser

Comment: Your code can pop multiple times if there are multiple matches. You could also fix it by using `else if` instead of multiple `if`.

Comment: Why are you putting strings in an array? Make a 2-dimensional array, and put a value in the filled elements.